# Postman. Добавить в переменную сессию из ответа

Tags: переменные, postman

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста как записать Session из ответа в переменную

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="GetNextStateResponse" Session="0fd50cea584f4183b83a1ca5fc2683d6492088975" ServiceId="19460" xmlns="http://ekassir.com/eKassir/PaySystem/Server/eKassirV3Protocol">
  <Result ResultCode="3" Message="" ProcessingErrorCode="0">
    <Parameters xmlns="" />
    <Errors xmlns="" />
  </Result>
```

Comment: Что бы значение Session="" из ответа записывалось  в переменную

Comment: Поправил вопрос Александр :)

Answer (score 0):

`var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);` - сначала преобразуйте XML в JSON.

`console.log(responseJson);` - видим все уровни к нужной нам переменной.

`pm.environment.set("Session", responseJson.Response.$.Session);` - В моем случае "Session" является объектом, "$" а он "Response"